# Tracking Invites discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a code that's supposed to track invites. If there is no mentioned member, then it will show your own invites, but if there is, it will show that member's invites.

```
@client.command()
async def invites(ctx, user = None):
  if user == None:
    totalInvites = 0
    for i in await ctx.guild.invites():
        if i.inviter == ctx.author:
            totalInvites += i.uses
    await ctx.send(f"You've invited {totalInvites} member{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'} to the server!")
  else:
    totalInvites = 0
    for i in await ctx.guild.invites():
       totalInvites += i.uses
       member = ctx.message.guild.get_member_named(user)
       await ctx.send(f"{member} has invited {totalInvites} member{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'} to the server!")
```

There's no error, instead, it just spams:
None has invited __ members to the server!
(__ is a random number.)

If there is no mentioned person, it works. How do I get this to send the number of invites the mentioned person has? Why does it spam the message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you forgot to check if your invite author is correct or not.
You loop over the invites, but don't have a `if i.inviter == member`.

The fixed code would be:

```py
@client.command()
async def invites(ctx, user = None):
  if user == None:
    totalInvites = 0
    for i in await ctx.guild.invites():
        if i.inviter == ctx.author:
            totalInvites += i.uses
    await ctx.send(f"You've invited {totalInvites} member{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'} to the server!")
  else:
    totalInvites = 0
    for i in await ctx.guild.invites():
       member = ctx.message.guild.get_member_named(user)
       if i.inviter == member:
         totalInvites += i.uses
    await ctx.send(f"{member} has invited {totalInvites} member{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'} to the server!")
```

Also, the reason it spammed is because you had your `await ctx.send` statement inside of your for-loop.